# Random number from 25 to 225 by 20 in c#?

Tags: c#, random, arc4random

How can I a random number from 25 to 225 by 20?
 For example: 25, 45 .65 ,85, 105 to 225?

Comment: Are these random numbers? This seems increment of 20.

Comment: Do you need any of those or all numbers?

Comment: Yes to random object location !!

Comment: Well, get a random number from 0 to 10, multiply if with 20 and add 25

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
....
int x = rnd.Next(11)*20 + 25; // or .Next(10), if 225 is exclusive
```

Comment: `nd.Next(6)*20 + 25;` the max value won't be just 125?

Comment: @AlexD Nope - `rand.Next(10)` picks number from `0..9`. It should be `Next(11)` :)

Comment: Sorry !! it's 225

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the acceptable values. i.e. 25,45,65, ... 255.
Use a random generated number to access the indexes of the array.
Get the value at that array index.
Happiness and joy abound in the world.